# How to search clients of the authenticated user?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a categorization in DB that a user has some clients, they are connected by user_id. At me, tables are shown in the dashboard that comes only clients that are registered by the currently logged-in user, but when I search by name or surname or mail at the table I see clients of other users.
This is the code?

```
public function render()
    {
        $user = Auth::user()->id;
        if($this->searchTerm == ''){
            return view('livewire.dashboard.user-management', [
                'clients' => Client::where('user_id', '=', $user)->orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortAsc)->paginate(8)
            ]);
        }
        else{
            return view('livewire.dashboard.user-management', [
                'clients' => Client::where('user_id', '=', $user)
                ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->searchTerm.'%')
                ->orWhere('surname', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->searchTerm.'%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->searchTerm.'%')
                ->orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortAsc)->paginate(8)
            ]);
        }
    }
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing your and/or clauses. You want to make sure that `user_id` is always respected, but the rest are maybes. To fix that, pass the `or` clauses into a closure:

```
return view('livewire.dashboard.user-management', [
    'clients' => Client::where('user_id', '=', $user)
        ->where(function($query) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->searchTerm.'%')
                ->orWhere('surname', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->searchTerm.'%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->searchTerm.'%');
        })
        ->orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortAsc)->paginate(8)
        
]);
```